# enable/disable datepicker with dropdown asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

i have dropdown for selecting data type of data in a textbox. dropdown options are like integer, decimal,string,date.

everything is working fine except one thing that is am unable to get a datepicker to the text box when dropdown is selected to date.

tried something like but failed to achieve

```
$(function () {
            $(".date1").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                numberOfMonths: 1

            });
        });

$("#<%=ddlDataType.ClientID %>").change(function () {
            if ($('#<%=ddlDataType.ClientID %> option:selected').text().toLowerCase() == "date") {
                $("#<%=txtDefaultValue.ClientID%>").prop("class", "date1");
            }
            else {
                $("#<%=txtDefaultValue.ClientID%>").prop("class", "");
            }
        });
```

what is the possible way to achieve this.

Comment: Are you using jQueryUI for your datepickers?

Comment: yes am using jQueryUI.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove it (keep it enable for other purpose) then you can use [destroy](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/datepicker/#method-destroy) method

```
$("#<%=txtDefaultValue.ClientID%>").datepicker("destroy");
```

else

You can set option enable and disable, on change event of ddlDataType drowndown list.

```
$("#<%=txtDefaultValue.ClientID%>").datepicker('enable');

$("#<%=txtDefaultValue.ClientID%>").datepicker('disable');
```

alternative you can also set options to enable disable datepicker

```
//To enable

$("#<%=txtDefaultValue.ClientID%>").datepicker( "option", "disabled", false );

//To disable

$("#<%=txtDefaultValue.ClientID%>").datepicker( "option", "disabled", true );
```

Comment: destroy is completely destroying the datepicker as i don't want that to happen bcoz user can select again date at that time datepicker should appear. enable/disable is disabling textbox that should be never has to happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want your datepicker to be shown or hidden, you can try this code (assuming you are using jQuery).

```
    if ($('#<%=ddlDataType.ClientID %> option:selected').text().toLowerCase() == "date") 
    {
              $(".date1").css("display", "block");
    }
    else {
              $(".date1").css("display", "none");
    }
```

Comment: i just wanted to disable datepicker.